# XML deserializer (Iserialzable)

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

I have a class in c# that implements Iserialzable.

I'm using a XMLSerializer that produces a XML from instance of that class.

I get the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SessionConfiguration>
    <RemoteMachineName>HV-BENDA</RemoteMachineName>
  </SessionConfiguration>
  <SessionsCredentialsList>
    <CredentialsItem>
      <User>test0</User>
      <Password>Pa$$word1</Password>
    </CredentialsItem>
    <CredentialsItem>
      <User>test1</User>
      <Password>Pa$$word1</Password>
    </CredentialsItem>
    <CredentialsItem>
      <User>test2</User>
      <Password>Pa$$word1</Password>
    </CredentialsItem>
    <CredentialsItem>
      <User>test3</User>
      <Password>Pa$$word1</Password>
    </CredentialsItem>
    <CredentialsItem>
      <User>test4</User>
      <Password>Pa$$word1</Password>
    </CredentialsItem>
  </SessionsCredentialsList>
  <TIME_OUT />
  <LOCAL_USERS_NUM>5</LOCAL_USERS_NUM>
</Configuration>
```

At some later point in the code I use a XMLSerializer again to deserial that XML document.

and I get the following error:

{"There is an error in XML document (1, 1)."}

Inner exception:

{"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}

Do someone knows wat could be the problem?

All the best

Comment: I'd guess an encoding issue. How are you storing the XML between serializing and deserializing? In a variable, as a file, in a database or ..?

Comment: `ISerializable` has nothing to do with XML serialization.  Can you post the code for the class you are trying to serialize?  You probably don't have the appropriate `System.Xml.Serialization` attributes applied to your properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely using only stream didn't work. Using StreamReader and StreamWriter solved it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usage of dollar sign might cause problems. Try using `&#36;` instead.